# WDIO - isDisplayed() method discrepencies in local & remote machines

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automation, synchronization, wdio-v5

cont elements = "list".filter(ele=> ele.isDisplayed());

Problem statement:
I am trying to get the list of displayed elements in WDIO, but currently its returning all elements in the list.

Note: Filter works fine in local machine, but not working in remote machine.

In order to get only displayed elements, Can you please suggest me the options ? Why i m seeing the different behavior in different machines ?

Appreciate if any hints

Comment: That code is synchronous. (Or, at least, if I ignore the errors in that code, it would be synchronous code.)

Comment: Thanks Robby . trying to solve the discrepancies even if the list data is same.